# i want binding image using image url

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I would like to read below XML and print the output in following order. Can you pls help with Query how to bind image?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Book>
   <L1 id="100">
     <Subjects>
       <subject>
          <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg1"/>
          <thumb_image>
         </subject>
       <subject>
         <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg2"/>
          <thumb_image>
      </subject>
       <subject>
          <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg3"/>
          <thumb_image>
       </subject>
     </Subjects>
   </L1>
  <L2 id="200">
     <Subjects>
       <subject>
         <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg"/1>
          <thumb_image>
       </subject>
       <subject>
           <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg2"/>
          <thumb_image>
       </subject>
       <subject>
          <thumb_image>
                <image url= url="http://dev2.merceed.jpeg2"/>
          <thumb_image>
       </subject>
     </Subjects>
   </L2>
<Book>
```

I want output like

100

Image1

Image2

Image3

.............

200

Image11

Image12

Image13

am using my code is

```
 var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("L1")
 from subject in l.Descendants("Subjects")
 select new Notch
 {
     name = (string)l.Attribute("id").Value,
     SubjectName= l.subject("article").Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("SubjectName")).ToList(),
      url = l.Element("article").Elements("thumb_image").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("url")).ToString()
     };

     foreach (var result in query)
     {
         foreach (var titles in result.SubjectName)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(titles);
         }
         foreach (var image in category.Image)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(image);
         }
     }
```

Comment: I think you made a typo, your `<Li id="200">` element is inside `<Li id="100">`, is this true? Also `subject` elements are not closed...

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense at the moment. Where does "article" come in?

Comment: no no.., L1 is header id

Comment: yeah, as Ivan suggested, you probably forgot to close your `<Li id="200">` element with a closing `</Li>` element. Additionaly, each `<Subject>` element needs to be closed with closing `</Subject>` element. If its already there, post the correct xml sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var query = 
      from l in xmlDoc.Root.Elements()
      select new {
         Id = (int)l.Attribute("id"),
         Subjects = l.Element("Subjects")
                     .Elements("subject")
                     .Select(s => (string)s.Attribute("SubjectName"))
                     .ToList()
      };

   foreach (var item in query)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item.Id);

       foreach (var name in item.Subjects)
           Console.WriteLine(name);
   }
```

UPDATE: After you have edited question (you have changed Li elements to L1 and L2 elements), you should use `xmlDoc.Root.Elements()` instead of `xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Li")`

Comment: hi i tried this code no output shows,when i put notch property that time only id value coming and Subjects shows like System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System]

Comment: @nagaraj What you can see in Subjects list in debugger? Set breakpoint on line `Console.WriteLine(item.Id)` and tell what you see inside `item` object.

Comment: ya i have done that, when am debugging that line that shows subjects List but not coming to ui so subjects lists are print like System.collection.Generic.List'1[system] so this am facing problem

Comment: and then if i didnt put Notch Property, i didnt get any ouput but no error shows if i added Notch Property result will shows but subjects list printing like that

Comment: @nagaraj that's because of instead enumeration of each subject, and displaying them on by one you do `Console.WriteLine(item.Subjects)`

Comment: ya i have done only shows System.Collections.Generic.List'1 same thing but id is not coming

Comment: so can you give me the proper query?

Comment: @nagaraj I already gave you - see code in answer above. There is two foreach loops. One for id, other for names.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear how you expect your current query to work (e.g. `l.subject`, and the use of `article` which doesn't appear in your XML) but I suspect you want something like:

```
var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Li")
            select new Notch
            {
                name = (string) l.Attribute("id"),
                SubjectName = l.Element("Subjects")
                               .Elements("subject")
                               .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("SubjectName"))
                               .ToList()
            };
```

I'd also *strongly* suggest you take a good look at your variable and property names. It doesn't make sense for a property called `SubjectName` to have a *collection* value, and it doesn't make sense for an iteration variable called `titles` to represent a *single* value. Paying attention to this sort of thing makes it much easier to maintain the code.

Comment: There is no `L1` elements in xml sample. Also there is subject names, not single name :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Fixed the `L1` part, but I don't know what you mean by the rest. The attribute in the XML is `SubjectName` and the property of `Notch` is apparently `SubjectName` (despite being clearly a collection). I've commented on the poor naming in my answer.

Comment: In your previous edit you had single selection of attribute for SubjectName, that comment was before you edited answer (well, at least before I refreshed your answer :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Ah, that makes sense. I only saw it *after* I'd made the edit :)